# bbswitch unable to turn discrete graphics off

Tags: power-management, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, bbswitch

> ```
> Laptop: Acer Predator PH315-52 
> OS : UBUNTU 18.04.2 LTS 
> Nvidia Driver : 418.87 
> Kernel : 5.0.0-37-generic 
> Processors : Intel UHD 630 and Nvidia 1660 Ti 
> bbswitch version: 0.8-4ubuntu1 
> bumblebee version: 3.2.1+git20181231-103~bionicppa1
> ```

```
$ grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog
```

Output:

> ```
> Predator bumblebeed[3353]: Received Terminated signal.
> Predator bumblebeed[3353]: Unable to disable discrete card.
> Predator bumblebeed[7981]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed started
> Predator bumblebeed[7981]: Unable to disable discrete card.
> ```

```
$ lsmod | grep -i nouveau
```

Output: (Blank output) ## showing nouveau is not loaded

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
```

Output:

i2c_nvidia_gpu ## Handled it via "$ modprobe -r i2c_nvidia_gpu" but the problem still remains
                 ## and the outputs of all too remains the same
                 ## Blank output of "lsmod | grep nvidia" after unloading it using ablove command

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

Ouput:0000:01:00.0 ON

```
$ sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<**OFF**
```

Output:OFF

```
$ dmesg | grep bbswitch


[ 6.659422] bbswitch: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 6.660407] bbswitch: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 6.661578] bbswitch: version 0.8
[ 6.662580] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[ 6.663575] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[ 6.665690] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[ 6.667873] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[ 18.818552] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 114.697607] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 114.697852] acpi_thermal_rel intel_pch_thermal wmi_bmof acer_wmi 
acer_wireless intel_lpss mac_hid soundcore sparse_keymap acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport bbswitch(OE) ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915 kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev vfio_iommu_type1 vfio kvm irqbypass i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm alx ahci mdio i2c_hid libahci i2c_nvidia_gpu hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake pinctrl_intel
[ 114.697897] bbswitch_off+0xbb/0x230 [bbswitch]
[ 114.697898] bbswitch_proc_write+0xb5/0xcc [bbswitch]
[ 446.444365] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics

$ cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

Ouput:0000:01:00.0 ON #############This is the problem,it should display OFF

```
$ optirun --status
```

Output: Bumblebee status: Ready (). X inactive. Discrete video card is on.

Also video LNXVIDEO:00: Failed to change power state to D3hot

**Installation steps taken:**

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Installed Cuda 10.1 .deb package from nvidia website and driver 418.87 was automatically
  installed with the package(also prime-select was also installed with it)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

changed - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\"'

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing

$ sudo apt update
```

Installed synaptics package manager and then through it installed bumblebee,bumblebee-nvidia
  and primus(and all others which by default get installed with them like bbswitch)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

> ```
>  Changed 'Driver=' to 'Driver=nvidia'
>   Bridge=primus
>   KernelDriver=nvidia
>   PMMethod=bbswitch
>   LibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
>   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
>   XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
> ```

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

> ```
>  blacklist nvidia
>   blacklist nvidia-current
>   blacklist nvidia-current-updates
>   blacklist nvidia_drm
>   blacklist nvidia_uvm
>   blacklist nvidia_modeset
>   blacklist nvidiafb
>   blacklist i2c-nvidia-gpu
>   blacklist i2c-nvidia-gpu
>   blacklist nouveau
>   blacklist nvidia-current
> ```

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
```

added following:

> i915
>
> bbswitch

selected intel as prime profile

Restarted laptop and the above stated problems kicked in.

Also upon startup grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog shows-
Predator bumblebeed[864]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed  started
Predator bumblebeed[864]: Unable to disable discrete card.

Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, on an msi laptop (GS65 stealth).

I just looked at the lsmod output and tried removing the module manually as well, right now. I'd bump your post but i just created this account.

Using the nvidia card on adaptive power mode at least saves you more battery (lasts about twice as much).

EDIT:
Disabling or blacklisting the i2c_nvidia_gpu module wont do anything. This module loads by default even when you don't have the nouveau or nvidia drivers installed, it has nothing to do with bumblebee/bbswitch apparently.

Bumblebee/prime are working correctly at first glance, the nvidia drivers are being deactivated and you're working with the intel integrated graphics, the problem seems to be that somehow, the nvidia GPU is still dragging a lot of power from the computer even when it is not in use (and should be OFF).

EDIT 2:

I found this other post regarding powering off the dedicated gpu, maybe this can work for you. I'll try it later:

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/78is1r/complete_disable_of_discrete_gpu/

EDIT3:
For me, selecting the Intel prime profile from the nvidia xserver settings (or `prime-select intel`), logging out then back in, and running

```
$ sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<**OFF**
```

manually works.

Are you sure nouveau is completely blacklisted? I had to add `balcklist=nouveau` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options in `/etc/default/grub`, and run `update-grub`, since the blacklist.conf file didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hello santiago...as you suggested, i added blacklist=nouveau to grub....... and then updated grub too but the results were still the same.Also i tried yout "EDIT 3" too ,doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the post you shared and that worked...Thanks Santiago

Comment: @ZERONULLS 

If you want to add a "Windows 2009" ( acpi_osi ), the steps are:

in the file /etc/default/grub, before GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash", write;

acpi_osi_name=Windows
edit GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT like this,
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='${acpi_osi_name} 2015'"

update-grub

if you run: sudo dmesg |grep -i added, you will get:

[    0.285056] ACPI: Added _OSI(Windows 2015)